# Logout flow makes no sense, leaves users confused

Tags: feature-request, users, user-experience, logout

I don't usually log out of my account, but recently decided to on a computer where I don't usually use Stack Overflow. The logout process is highly confusing and I'm not sure what actually happens when I attempt to logout. (Are there statistics on how many people actually log out of their accounts? Maybe that could help drive the discussion.)

When I click on "Logout" what I expect to happen is that I am immediately logged out from the site I'm on, on the machine I'm currently working on. Instead, when I logout from Stack Overflow, I'm presented with some sort of choice. Before I even look at the choice, I no longer know whether I'm still logged in or not. Did clicking "Logout" log me out as expected? Or do I need to answer this question before I am actually logged out? To me, this is a security issue since a user cannot tell what has happened.

Because I'm conditioned by commercial websites to ignore anything presented at logout as either an advertisement for a service I don't need or a trick to "keep me engaged," I generally don't read anything after I press a logout button and just close the browser. But because this is Stack Overflow, I decided to read the message today and I realized that I have no idea whether it already logged me out or not.

This is horrible UI. A typical user probably:

1. Does not notice that they weren't logged out because they've also been trained to ignore anything after logging out
2. Does not understand the text of the message (as evidenced by the other questions here asking what it means)

At the very least, the text should tell you whether you have actually logged out already or have not yet completed logout. Something like:

> NOTE! You are not yet logged out of Stack Overflow. By clicking below you  will log yourself out of Stack Overflow and all of the following domains:

As it stands right now, it's extremely confusing. In reality, it should just log you out without presenting you with more choices, especially choices that most users won't be able to understand. (Why is it telling me about the ubuntu site? I've never logged in there! Does it think I'm logged in there?)

If the problem being solved by this intermediate step is that logging out from one site logs you out from other sites you might be using as mentioned in other logout questions, then that should be fixed separately, in my opinion. While I can see that being an annoyance, it seems like a huge security risk to not log someone out after they press the logout button and walk away.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward as is to me. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ *"Clicking “Log out” will log you out of the following domains on this device:"* Clearly... if it's asking you to click "log out" to log out... you're not logged out yet. Additional text saying you aren't logged out yet would be redundant (and fall into your same argument that noone reads that page)

Comment: It's a glorified "are you sure?" dialog. Unfortunately it's in a place where the average user doesn't expect there to be any.

Comment: I disagree that it's straightforward. If I'm logging out of StackOverflow, I have to notice that "StackOverflow" is something like 7th on the list. After reading a few entries, I think the average person would just be like, "What are these other sites? This doesn't apply to me." closes the window, leaving them not actually logged out.